# How do I stop my batch script from outputting ECHO is off when it enters a variable into a file?

Tags: command-line, batch

I made a script that pastes a variable into a file but whenever it pastes the text from the variable it says ECHO is off.

Here is the script I used:

```
@echo off
color 0c
title vmfMerge v1.1 by bub
echo Welcome to vmfMerge! Note that the first file you choose will be DELETED!
echo Name and extension of vmf? (example.vmf)
set /p firstfile=
cls
echo Name and extension of second vmf?
set /p secondfile=
cls
del %firstfile%
set /p content=<%firstfile%
echo %content% >> %secondfile%
```

I need it to stop adding that into the file.

Comment: You delete %firstfile% then set content from it, so **content is ALWAYS EMPTY**, and when you try to write it `echo` with no/empty operand(s) outputs `ECHO is {ON|OFF}.` as applicable.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your script is that the `%content%` variable is empty. This is because you are trying to read the content of `%firstfile%` after you have deleted it with the `del` command.

To fix this, you should switch the order of the `del` and `set /p` commands.